# Cassandra reads slow with multiple nodes

Tags: cassandra

I have a three node Cassandra cluster with version 2.0.5.
RF=3 and all data is synced to all three nodes.
I read from cqlsh with Consistency=ONE.
When I bring down two of the nodes my reads are twice as fast than when I have the entire cluster up.
Tracing from cqlsh shows that the slow down on the reads with a full cluster up occurs when a request is forwarded to other nodes. 
All nodes are local to the same datacenter and there is no other activity on the system.
So, why are requests sometimes forwarded to other nodes?
Even for the exact same key if I repeat the same query multiple times I see that sometimes the query executes on the local node and sometimes it gets forwarded and then becomes very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the cluster isn't overloaded, Cassandra should always prefer to do local reads when possible.  Can you create a bug report at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA ?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. I created JIRA
CASSANDRA-6731

Answer (score 1):

This is due to read repair.
By default read repair is applied for all the read with consistency level quorum or with 10% chance for lower consistency levels, that's why for consistency level one sometimes you see more activity and sometime less activity.

Comment: I use read_repair_chance=0. So I don't believe this is due to read repair. Even if this was the case I see these redirects much more often than for 10% of my queries.

Comment: when reads or writes are initiated at a node, that node acts as a coordinator and will forward the request to appropriate number of nodes based on replication factor. it chooses the nodes to forward the read request based on their performance history. so in cases that request is being forwarded it is possible that the coordinator thinks that another node has a better performance and should forward the request to that node

Comment: Is there a way not to forward these requsts and have them always processed locally?

Comment: I don't think so. As in general, there is no guaranty that the local node owns the data. When you have 3+ nodes and rf=3, there are defiantly records not local to your node. what is the delay you are experiencing?

Comment: Reads are twice as slow when I get a redirect. I tried disabling the dynamic snitch and setting a network topoogy strategy with every node on a different rack but it did not make a difference.